# Hibernate envers - Filter results using "IN" condition

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I'm using hibernate (5.4.32) envers to audit my tables and I want to retrieve all the results that matching certain criteria with the "IN" condition, example:

```
AuditQuery auditQ = auditReader.createQuery()
                   .forRevisionsOfEntity(TABLEX.class, false, true)
                   .add(AuditEntity.property("state").in(listStateIds));
```

If I try to do that I'm getting the following error:

> Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/app/] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: This criterion cannot be used on a property that is a relation to another property.; nested exception is org.hibernate.envers.exception.AuditException: This criterion cannot be used on a property that is a relation to another property.] with root cause

Any idea how to workaround this? Native SQL?
Thanks

Comment: [This](https://blog-doubleslash-de.translate.goog/hibernate-envers-suche?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=de&_x_tr_pto=wapp) blog post (via Google Translate) suggests to use `or` instead of `in`. Appears to be a limitation of the `AuditReader` API, at least with 5.x?

Comment: yes, it looks like a limitation with hibernate envers. For now i'm using native SQL